# Prevent Bootstrap row from taking height of tallest child column element, and use the empty space under smaller element

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5.2.
The idea is to create two columns that are both col-md-6 inside a row. This image is a general idea of what the layout looks like: https://prnt.sc/FaIB3CZMJrO_.

The issue I'm running into is that I can't create another row with col-md-6 elements inside of it to fit directly under the ExampleTitle column. Here is what ends up happening: https://prnt.sc/YZtp1MJqjQMD.

This is what I'm trying to do but in an image so it's easier to understand: https://prnt.sc/i7w4jVN38uz5.

For reference, this is the design idea that I'm trying to go for that I came across (you have to scroll down a bit): https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

```css
.card2 {
  background: #2b2b2b;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  border-radius: 16px;
}
body {
  background-color: #131313;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, a, p {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>ExampleTitle</h2>
      <div class="card2">
        <h4>ExampleItem1</h4>
        <p>Description</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card2">
        <h4>ExampleItem2</h4>
        <p>Description</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card2">
        <h4>ExampleItem3</h4>
        <p>Description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>ExampleTitle2</h2>
      <div class="card2">
        <h4>Service1</h4>
        <p>Something</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card2">
        <h4>Service2</h4>
        <p>Something that is a longer sentence and will occupy a new line so that they arent the exact same heights</p>
    </div>
      <div class="card2">
        <h4>Service3</h4>
        <p>Something</p>
    </div>
      <div class="card2">
        <h4>Service4</h4>
        <p>Something</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>ExampleTitle2</h2>
      <div class="card2">
        <h4>Service1</h4>
        <p>Something</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card2">
        <h4>Service2</h4>
        <p>Something that is a longer sentence and will occupy a new line so that they arent the exact same heights</p>
    </div>
      <div class="card2">
        <h4>Service3</h4>
        <p>Something</p>
    </div>
      <div class="card2">
        <h4>Service4</h4>
        <p>Something</p>
    </div>
    </div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: add code of what you have

Comment: I added HTML and CSS to the original post, but it won't show the two columns because the thing that it's being rendered in isn't large enough to show both columns.

Comment: No worries, it shows in two columns when clicked on `Full page`.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a special reason you do not move the contents of your third column into the first one? If needed, you can put some top margin to the first child of the third column so it looks separated. Something like:

```css
.card2 {
  background: #2b2b2b;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

body {
  background-color: #131313;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
a,
p {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>ExampleTitle</h2>
      <div class="card2">
        <h4>ExampleItem1</h4>
        <p>Description</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card2">
        <h4>ExampleItem2</h4>
        <p>Description</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card2">
        <h4>ExampleItem3</h4>
        <p>Description</p>
      </div>
      <h2 class="mt-5">ExampleTitle2</h2>
      <div class="card2">
        <h4>Service1</h4>
        <p>Something</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card2">
        <h4>Service2</h4>
        <p>Something that is a longer sentence and will occupy a new line so that they arent the exact same heights</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card2">
        <h4>Service3</h4>
        <p>Something</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card2">
        <h4>Service4</h4>
        <p>Something</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>ExampleTitle2</h2>
      <div class="card2">
        <h4>Service1</h4>
        <p>Something</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card2">
        <h4>Service2</h4>
        <p>Something that is a longer sentence and will occupy a new line so that they arent the exact same heights</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card2">
        <h4>Service3</h4>
        <p>Something</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card2">
        <h4>Service4</h4>
        <p>Something</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```